# How to insert follower to this relation

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I have this realtion

```
@ManyToMany(() => User, user => user.following)
@JoinTable()
followers: User[]

@ManyToMany(() => User, user => user.followers)
following: User[]
```

How to insert new follower to this relation?
Im new to typeorm and sql databases

Comment: [It could help you. please have a look.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54886350/9808302)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by enabling cascades:

```
@ManyToMany(() => User, user => user.following, {cascadeInsert: true, cascadeUpdate: true})
@JoinTable()
followers: User[]

@ManyToMany(() => User, user => user.followers, {cascadeInsert: true, cascadeUpdate: true})
following: User[]
```

If you don't want to use cascadeInsert and cascadeUpdate, you have to save the related entities manually:

```
const follower1 = new Follower({...});
await connection.manager.save(follower1);

const follower2 = new Follower({...});
await connection.manager.save(follower2);

const entity = new Entity();
entity.followers = [follower1, follower2];
await connection.manager.save(entity);
```

See TypeORM docs for details: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/many-to-many-relations.md)